# onChange javascript not work in linux

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, linux, windows

I have an onChange inside an ajax, this works well on Windows but not so on Linux, on Linux it just does not call the onchange function.

```
$verarch .= "<img src='" . PATH_DOMAIN . "/web/lib/32/book3.png' file='".$una['fil_id']."' restric='".$una['fil_confidencialidad']."' class='tipodocumento icon' title='Cambiar de tipo documental' /><span style='display:none' id='cambiartipodoc" . $una['fil_id'] . "'>";
$verarch .= "<select name='' id='tra_id" . $una['fil_id'] . "' onChange='buscarcuerpo(".$_POST['cue_id'].",".$una['fil_id'].")'>";
$verarch .= "<option value='0'>-</option>";
foreach ($grupDoc as $un1) {
  $verarch .="<option value=" . $un1['tra_id'] . ">" . $un1['tra_id'] . "</option>";
}
$verarch .="</select>";
```

This section is called by an ajax, calls a function buscarcuerpo().

```
function buscarcuerpo(id_cuerpo, id_archivo) {
    console.log('Wil');
    var url = "<?php echo $PATH_DOMAIN ?>/archivo/ajaxcargarcuerpo/";

    $("#cuerpocambio" + id_archivo).load(url, {id_cuerpo: id_cuerpo, id: id_archivo});
}
```

console.log('Wil'). On the Linux server it does not print "Wil" but in Windows itself.

Please a help.

Comment: You mean it doesn't works in a browser running on linux right? Which browser?

Comment: Does not work in any browser, when it is in linux

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the callback in your browser. Try posting the actual html and JavaScript instead of the PHP that generates it.

Comment: What is `PATH_DOMAIN`? It probably changes according to platform right ? Double check it on generated source code. It might be breaking your js only on linux.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: PATH_DOMAIN, It works correctly, since if it shows the image, in console I do not get any error.

Comment: I think you need to escape quotation because you mixing ' and " with PHP and HTML

Comment: like that 

onChange=\"buscarcuerpo(" . $_POST['cue_id'].", " . $una['fil_id'] . ")\"

Comment: But in the html at the time of generating it shows me correctly, <select name="" id="tra_id56934" onchange="buscarcuerpo(889,56934)"><option value="0">-</option><option value="3545">3545</option><option value="144">144</option></select>

Comment: Sorry, I tried the advice of domos but it does not work. :(